# How to do Explicit mapping in elasticsearch Nodejs client

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm using the Javascript client in nodejs for elasticsearch, but it doesn't seem very clear to me how to set the type of a document using the elasticsearch nodejs module.

The problem I'm facing is that I'm pulling a JSON object from one of our vendor's API, and one of the attributes in that object is "rank". Rank is a floating-point value, but for whatever reason the vendor is returning it as a string. Thus, when I enter the document in elasticsearch, elasticsearch interprets that attribute as a string too and I cannot perform queries like this one:

```
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/backlinks/profile/_search?pretty=true' -d '
{ 
    "query" : { 
        "match_all" : {}
    } ,
    "facets": {
        "range1" : {
            "range" : {
                "field" : "rank",
                "ranges" : [
                    {"from" : "5.5", "to": "7.00"}
                ]
            }
        }
    }'
```

because it returns the following exception:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Number`

I know that I can do explicit mapping when I'm creating the index, but is there any way to do this using the nodejs module?

I can't find that option in the documentation, and I find it a bit cumbersome to explicitly send a GET request to the elastic search server, when an API already exists.

Also, is explicit mapping recursive?

Say my vendor sends me this:

```
{
  name: 'wallets',
  price: '15.00',
  relatedItems: [{name: 'purses', price:'12.00'}, {name:'bags', price:'11.00'}]
};
```

If I do explicit mapping on that object like this:

```
price: { 
    type: 'float'
}
```

will that type map to all attributes named 'price' ? or will it only apply to the first one?

Thanks!